# using the pytest.fixture scope function on setup_class

Tags: python, pytest

I have two test case modules **TestClassA, TestClassB**. On test_1_that_needs_resource_a in TeseClass A, I am using fixture so I can call resource_a and pass parameters before executing testcase. How can I use the same fixture on setup_class in TestClassB so all testcase
in TestClassB so the fixture can be called one time before all testcase in TestClassB

```
import pytest

@pytest.fixture(scope='function')
def resource(request):
    print('resources_a_setup()')
    return request.param

class TestClassA:
    @classmethod
    def setup_class(cls):
        print('\nsetup_class()')

    @classmethod
    def teardown_class(cls):
        print('\nteardown_class()')

    @pytest.mark.parametrize('resource', [dict(), dict(name=1)], indirect=['resource'])
    def test_1_that_needs_resource_a(self, resource):
        assert resource == dict()
        print(f'\ntest_1_that_needs_resource_a(), {resource}')


class TestClassB:
    ## I would like to call resource fixture with passing some parameter on setup_class here
    @classmethod
    def setup_class(cls):
        print('\nsetup_class()')

    @classmethod
    def teardown_class(cls):
        print('\nteardown_class()')

    def test_1_that_needs_resource_a(self):
        print('\ntest_1_that_needs_resource_a()')
```

Comment: Why don't you create a [conftest.py](https://docs.pytest.org/en/2.7.3/plugins.html?highlight=re) file and move your fixtures there, so they are available in either module.

Comment: I can, but how does it help me to use the same fixture on setup_class on moduleA and testcas on moduleB?

Comment: Do you need the setup resource strictly in the `setup_class` method? If not, maybe you could overwrite resource fixture in `TestClassB` using `autouse`: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/unittest.html#using-autouse-fixtures-and-accessing-other-fixtures

Comment: yes, and I have tried to use **autouse** as well..but i only want setup resource to be run on **etup_class** on TestClassB